# Is there a way to return a HttpResponseServerError for a Djangular djangoRMI method call?

Tags: python, json, django, httpresponse, djangular

I have several methods that use [djangular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) remote method invocation.

Currently when one of these fails, I just return a dict/json with an error property that I check for on the JavaScript side if my app.

```
@allow_remote_invocation
def do_a_thing(self):
    return {'error':'oops', 'description':'the thing broke'}
```

This is fine,  but occasionally the method breaks outside of Python's control,  and I need to use the error_callback on the JavaScript side.

I end up replicating the error handling,  which makes me cry at night.

```
function call_the_thing(){
    djangoRMI.do_a_thing().then(function(data){
        if(data.error){
            handleError(data.error)
        }else{
            ....
        }
    },function(rejectReason){
        handleError(rejectReason)
    }
}
```

What I thought the day,  is that there had to be a way to return and error from the python side,  not just a success with error data.

I was hoping I could wrap by python dict in a `HttpResponseServerError` but I can't fathom how to do more than return more than string, nor how to make it for with Djangular.

Is this the correct way to return a server error (as `HttpResponseServerError`)? Or because of djangular I need to treat it as a nation ah I have been doing?

n.b. I haven't been able to spend/waste time at work *yet*. When I do, if there's not a decent answer here I'll self-answer. But I'm also interested in what is good practice add returning JSON feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JSONResponseException](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular/blob/master/djangular/views/mixins.py#L23)**

It's thrown like a regular django exception, but the message kwarg can take JSON content. It defaults to a response status of 400, but that can be set with another kwarg.

So now you can write:

```
@allow_remote_invocation
def do_a_thing(self):
    if not thing.do():
        return thing.do()
    message = {'error':'oops', 'description':'the thing broke'}
    status = 500
    raise JSONResponseException(message=message,status=status)
```